How to patch (redefine) the standalone's \subpreamble command?
I'd like to patch (redefine) the standalone's \subpreamble command but my attempts seem to fail. Here's an MCE that I expect to fail to compile because of the \aaa command, but it doesn't:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname1.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Content of \jobname1 file.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Content of \jobname2 file.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\NewCommandCopy {\origsubpreamble} {\subpreamble}
\RenewDocumentCommand {\subpreamble} { m } {
  \aaa                                                     % <--- HERE
  \origsubpreamble{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\input{\jobname1}

\section{Test 2}
\input{\jobname2}
\end{document}

In my real use case, \aaa is supposed to be a command that stores the argument of the \subpreamble command which turns to be the name of the input file, the .sta file that stores all the sub-preambles of the sub-files being in the context of the previous MCE (here \jobname being test):
\standalonepreambles
\subpreamble{test1.tex}
 
\endsubpreamble
\subpreamble{test2.tex}
 
\endsubpreamble
\endstandalonepreambles

Why \aaa is ignored and to make it not be ignored?
Edit (sorry, a bit long)
The reason I want to patch the \subpreamble{⟨subfile⟩} command in order to get its argument (i.e. the name of the ⟨subfile⟩ whose preamble follows in the . sta) is as follows: I have created a class which uses the standalone package to input (\input) files which can be standalone LaTeX documents, i.e. with \documentclass, preamble and document environment. This class also uses the attachfile2 package to attach to the end of each sub-document in the “global” document, the source of this sub-document along with all the associated files so that the reader has all the files needed to compile the sub-document. To do this:

I created a sequence intended to contain a list of files to be attached to the sub-document (this sequence is cleared for each sub-document inputed);
I patched the \includegraphics{⟨image_file⟩} command so that ⟨image_file⟩ was added to the list of files to be attached;
I did the same for other commands, for example \lstinputlisting{⟨listing_file⟩};
I created (as suggested in the comments) a command (say) \myinput{⟨subfile⟩} which:

places ⟨subfile⟩ in the list of files to attach;
at the end of the inputed sub-document, attaches the files in the list.



This works very well because all the files to be attached are added in the the document body as the sub-documents are composed. However, for bibliography files added using the biblatex's \addbibresource, a patch such as the one applied to the \includegraphics{⟨image_file⟩} command does not work because \addbibresource can only be used as a preamble: as a result, an \addbibresource command in the preamble of a sub-document is not read when this sub-document is composed, but it is read at the same time as all the other \addbibresource commands contained in the other sub-documents' preambles, just when the .sta file is read (in the preamble of the global document):
\subpreamble{⟨subfile_1⟩}
[...]
\addbibresource {⟨subfile_1⟩.bib}
[...]
\endsubpreamble
\subpreamble{⟨subfile_2⟩}
[...]
\addbibresource {⟨subfile_2⟩.bib}
[...]
\endsubpreamble
[...]
\subpreamble{⟨subfile_n⟩}
[...]
\addbibresource {⟨subfile_n⟩.bib}
[...]
\endsubpreamble

We can see above that, in order for ⟨subfile_1⟩.bib to be added to the list of files to be attached to the source sub-document ⟨subfile_1⟩.tex, the patch of the \addbibresource command would have to be able to have knowledge of the current sub-document ⟨subfile_1⟩.tex.
I hope I've made myself clearer.

so what about using a command hook? there's also the advice/collargs packages, but a generic hook would be better if it can work .... see lthooks-doc e.g. \AddToHook{cmd/subpreamble/before} (note: I haven't checked this - just going by memory so might not be exactly right). the thing about this is that you can inject code in advance of the command being defined. so you should be able (maybe) to work around the sequencing issue without having to fork the .sty.

@cfr Unfortunaltely, I already tried to rely on hooks but it doesn't work. In my MCE above, if you replace \NewCommandCopy {\origsubpreamble} {\subpreamble} and \RenewDocumentCommand {\subpreamble} { m } { ... } by \AddToHook{cmd/subpreamble/before}{\aaa}, the compilation doesn't fail (hence \aaa is never seen).

yes, you'd have to actually change things there, which seems non-ideal. which makes advice look more attractive ....

biblatex stores the names of bib files in the (etoolbox-)list \blx@bibfiles. Wouldn't is be easier to simply process this list to attach the bib files?

@UlrikeFischer But could such a list be aware of the ⟨subfile_k⟩.tex file where the names of the .bib files were added as bib resources?

if each file has exactly one .bib file, it would be easy, right? because you could just use them in order. it's not clear whether that's guaranteed here or whether some files might have no and/or multiple resource lines?

@cfr No, there's no guarantee each file has exactly one .bib file: some files might have no and/or multiple resource lines.

It would know all files you added in the current compilation and so all files you probably need for the citation. Isn't that what you want?

@UlrikeFischer No: for each .bib file added to one of the .tex sub-files, I need to know the name of that sub-file.

standalone ignore the subfiles preambles using a command named \sa@gobble. This command is defined with:
\long\def\sa@gobble#1\begin#2{%
  ...

It is used to redefine \documentclass, setting #2 to document; #1 hold thus the preamble content.
You can patch \sa@gobble to recover the preamble. For example, with etoolbox:
\pretocmd{\sa@gobble}{%
  \gdef\currentpreamble{#1}%
}

Then \currentpreamble contains the preamble of the last input file. You can, for example, parse it or write it in a file.
Below, an example of parsing using regular expressions:
\seq_new:N \g_denis_extracted_files_seq

\cs_new:Nn \denis_extract_files_for:nn
    {
      \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
      \regex_extract_all:nnNT
        { \c{ #1 } \{ ( .*? ) \} } { #2 } \l_tmpa_seq
        {
          % get capturing groups
          \bool_while_do:nn
            {
              \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_seq { \c_false_bool } { \c_true_bool }
            }
            {
              \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl % full pattern
              \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl % capturing group
              \seq_gput_right:NV \g_denis_extracted_files_seq \l_tmpa_tl
            }
        }
    }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \denis_extract_files_for:nn { en }

\cs_new:Nn \denis_extract_files_for:Nn
    {
      \denis_extract_files_for:en { \cs_to_str:N #1 }{ #2 }
    }

\denis_extract_files_for:Nn \addbibresource { <preamble> } will look for the pattern \addbibresource{...} in <preamble> and store in \g_denis_extracted_files_seq the content inside braces (we need two \seq_pop:NN as the first is the full match and the second the capturing group we want the extract).
Add some user commands to extract the desired pattend
\NewDocumentCommand { \extractfilesfor }{ m m }
    {
      \denis_extract_files_for:Nn #1 { #2 }
    }

show found files
\NewDocumentCommand { \showextractedfiles }{ }
    {
      \seq_if_empty:NTF \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
        {
          No~files~found!
        }
        {
          \par\bigskip
          Extracted~file(s):
          \begin{itemize}
            \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
                {
                    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { ##1 }
                    \item \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str
                }
          \end{itemize}
        }
    }

and clear the sequence that store the list of files
\NewDocumentCommand { \clearextractedfiles }{ }
    {
      \seq_clear:N \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
    }

Finally, patch \sa@gobble with \extractfilesfor
\pretocmd{\sa@gobble}{%
  \extractfilefor{\addbibresource}{#1}%
}

Example:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname1.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\addbibresource {subfile1_ressource1.bib}
\addbibresource {subfile1_ressource2.bib}
\addbibresource {subfile1_ressource3.bib}
\begin{document}
Content of \jobname1 file.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\addbibresource {subfile2_ressource1.bib}
\begin{document}
Content of \jobname2 file.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_denis_extracted_files_seq

\cs_new:Nn \denis_extract_files_for:nn
    {
      \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
      \regex_extract_all:nnNT
        { \c{ #1 } \{ ( .*? ) \} } { #2 } \l_tmpa_seq
        {
          % get capturing groups
          \bool_while_do:nn
            {
              \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_seq { \c_false_bool } { \c_true_bool }
            }
            {
              \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl % full pattern
              \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl % capturing group
              \seq_gput_right:NV \g_denis_extracted_files_seq \l_tmpa_tl
            }
        }
    }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \denis_extract_files_for:nn { en }

\cs_new:Nn \denis_extract_files_for:Nn
    {
      \denis_extract_files_for:en { \cs_to_str:N #1 }{ #2 }
    }

\NewDocumentCommand { \extractfilesfor }{ m m }
    {
      \denis_extract_files_for:Nn #1 { #2 }
    }

\NewDocumentCommand { \showextractedfiles }{ }
    {
      \seq_if_empty:NTF \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
        {
          No~files~found!
        }
        {
          \par\bigskip
          Extracted~file(s):
          \begin{itemize}
            \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
                {
                    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str { ##1 }
                    \item \str_use:N \l_tmpa_str
                }
          \end{itemize}
        }
    }

\NewDocumentCommand { \clearextractedfiles }{ }
    {
      \seq_clear:N \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\sa@gobble}{%
  \extractfilesfor{\addbibresource}{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\addbibresource[1]{
  % dummy command for test
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\input{\jobname1}

\showextractedfiles

\clearextractedfiles

\section{Test 2}
\input{\jobname2}

\showextractedfiles

\end{document}



Many thanks for this very clever answer! It took me some time to understand why you relied on regex. I was hoping to avoid that and get away with patching the addbibresource command so that its argument was stored directly in the l_tmpa_seq sequence, but if that worked it didn't limit the addition to the underlying .tex subfiles.

@DenisBitouzé I added some explanations. You can't patch \addbibresource as is it not evaluated when the file is loaded.

The standalone.sty code contains
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\subpreamble\@gobble
  \let\endsubpreamble\relax
  \let\standalonepreambles\relax
  \let\endstandalonepreambles\relax
  \ifsa@sortsubpreambles
    \let\sa@orig@usepackage\usepackage
    \let\usepackage\sa@usepackagewithoutoptions
  \fi
  \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.sta}{}{}%
...

so it redefines \subpreamble to gobble its argument before doing \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.sta}{}{}.  A redefinition in preamble after loading of standalone thus has no effect.
The actual action of \subpreamble happens during loading of standalone.sty via
\long\gdef\subpreamble#1#2\endsubpreamble{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname prevsubpreamble@#1\endcsname{#2}%
  \ifsa@sortsubpreambles
    \sa@scanpackages#2\usepackage\sa@endmarker
  \fi
}
\def\endsubpreamble{}%
\ifsa@printsubpreambles
  \immediate\openout\sa@out=\jobname.stp\relax
\else
\begingroup
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \makeatother
    \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.sta}{}{\PackageInfo{standalone}{STA file not found!}{}{}}%
  }%
\endgroup

Its effect is to define some macros whose names are in relations to the subfiles names. The effect is done immediately after definition.  You will need to patch those \prevsubpreamble@<filename> macros.
It would seem the simplest is to copy standalone.sty to your own version and do your patches in there.

Copying standalone.sty into my own version and making my patches there, that's what I considered but hoped could be avoided :)

I post here a code, heavily based (though a little simplified) on the accepted answer, that answers the problem I in fact wanted to solve in the edited of  the present question.
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test1.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test1-1.bib}
\addbibresource[glob]{test1-2.bib}
\addbibresource{test1-3.bib}
\begin{document}
See \autocite{bibkey1-1,bibkey1-2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test1-1.bib}
@article{bibkey1-1,
  title = {A Title 1-1},
  author = {Author 1-1, An},
  date = {2024-10-13},
  journaltitle = {A Journal 1-1},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test1-2.bib}
@article{bibkey1-2,
  title = {A Title 1-2},
  author = {Author 1-2, An},
  date = {2024-10-13},
  journaltitle = {A Journal 1-2},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test1-3.bib}
@article{bibkey1-3,
  title = {A Title 1-3},
  author = {Author 1-3, An},
  date = {2024-10-13},
  journaltitle = {A Journal 1-3},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test2.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test2.bib}
\begin{document}
See \autocite{bibkey2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test2.bib}
@article{bibkey2,
  title = {A Title 2},
  author = {Author 2, An},
  date = {2024-10-13},
  journaltitle = {A Journal 2},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[icon=Paperclip]{attachfile2}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_denis_extracted_files_seq

\cs_new:Nn \denis_extract_file_for:nn
{
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \regex_extract_all:nnNT
  {
    \c{ #1 } \[?.*?\]?        \{ ( .*? ) \}
  }
  {
    #2
  }
  \l_tmpa_seq
  {
    % get capturing groups
    \bool_while_do:nn
    {
      \seq_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_seq { \c_false_bool } { \c_true_bool }
    }
    {
      \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl % full pattern
      \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl % capturing group
      \seq_gput_right:NV \g_denis_extracted_files_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myinput}{ s m }{
  \begin{refsection}
    \input { #2 }
  \end{refsection}
  \seq_if_empty:NTF \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
  {
    No~files~found!
  }
  {
    \par\noindent
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
    {
      \attachfile[
        description={
          Fichier~ bibliographique~ utilisé~ dans~ le~
          présent~ article~ (fichier~ `\tl_to_str:n{##1}`)
          },
          mimetype=application/x-bib
        ]
      {\tl_to_str:n{##1}}
    }
  }
  \seq_clear:N \g_denis_extracted_files_seq
}
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/sa@gobble/before}{
  \denis_extract_file_for:nn { addbibresource }{ #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\myinput{\jobname1}

\section{Test 2}
\myinput{\jobname2}
\end{document}

